# Data binding with custom object not refreshing UI when adding object in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, data-binding, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have a MAUI app. I have an object `Comment` with a `List<Note>` of `Note`-objects inside:

```cs
public class Comment {
   public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Now in my `MainPage.xaml` I want to display all `Note`s of my `Comment`. For this I have built a `<ListView>`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="VisitMaui.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:VisitMaui.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainViewModel"
             xmlns:Classes="clr-namespace:PersonalBibleindex.Classes"
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:VisitMaui.Controls">    

        <Label Text="Notes/>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Comment.Notes}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type Classes:Note}">
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Text}"></TextCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

If I load `Note`s into my List manually this works fine. But now I want to create `Note`s dynamically by clicking on a button:

```xml
<Button Text="Add note" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
```

Whereas the `Add`-function in my ViewModel looks like this:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
void Add()
    {
        Note MyNote = new Note();
        MyNote.VerseWords = "DasWort";
        MyNote.Text = "Testnotiz";
        Comment.Notes.Add(MyNote);
        Counter++;
    }
```

My problem: When I click on the `Add note`-Button, a new note will be added to `Comment.Notes`-List,  but the UI doesn't refresh. What am I missing?

Comment: You could refer to [Populate a ListView with data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-7.0#populate-a-listview-with-data)

Answer (score 3):

You need an [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx), so try changing `List<Note>` to `ObservableCollection<Note>`

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `ViewModel` class does not implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to make the View layer aware of data changes, please refer to [Updating views in response to changes in the underlying view model or model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm) for more details.

For how to solve this problem, you could refer to MAUI's official MVVM standard example: [Data binding and MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm) for more details about how to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.